# Eclispe RCP: Copying files from package folder of a plugin into an arbitary place of the filesystem

Tags: file, copy, package, eclipse-rcp

In one of my plugins in my eclipse RCP I'm storing some property files.

Package: `com.demo.my.package` contains two files:

```
File1.properties
File2.properties
```

How can I copy, during runtime, the content of the `com.demo.my.package` to an arbitary place on the filesystem?

**Note:** I don't know how many files are in the `com.demo.my.package`.

I just gave two filenames as an example.

So far I have been trying to get an `URL` instance of the package folder using

```
 URL url = Platform.getBundle(pluginId).getEntry(path);
```

where pluginID is the ID of the plugin of the package and path is the following String:

`com/demo/my/package`

This call results in a `null` value so I'm stuck here.

It may be an easy task if I just deploy the plugin in a flat structure but I would prefere to **not** do that.

Any ideas how to copy the content of a package to another place in the filesystem during runtime?

**Solution:**

1. Create a new scource folder called **texts** in the root of the plugin which contains the files to copy.
2. Gain URL of the source folder via my custom function:

   ```
   public String getLocalFilePath(String pluginId, String path) {
   URL url = Platform.getBundle(pluginId).getEntry(path);

   try {
       String filepath = FileLocator.toFileURL(url).toString();
       filepath = filepath.replace("/", "\\");
       filepath = filepath.substring(6, filepath.length());

       return filepath;
   } catch (IOException e1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }

   return null;
   ```

   }
3. Copy files

   ```
   File sourceDirectory = new File(source);
   File[] listOfFiles = sourceDirectory.listFiles();

   for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
       String sourcePath = source + "\\" + listOfFiles[i].getName();
       String destPath = targetDirectoryString + "\\" + listOfFiles[i].getName();
       try {
           copyFileUsingChannel(new File(sourcePath), new File(destPath));
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }



   private static void copyFileUsingChannel(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
       FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
       FileChannel destChannel = null;
       try {
           sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
           destChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
           destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
       } finally {
           sourceChannel.close();
           destChannel.close();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Did you tried guava or apache common libraries to copy file or folder(s)?

Comment: I'm planning on using the apache library yes but those methods expect an URL as a parameter. I managed to get such an URL by adding a new source folder to my plugin , putting the property files there and requesting the url of the new source folder. At the moment I'm trying to figure out why FileUtil.copyDirectory(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory); isn't working. Target is a valid URL on the file system and source is the path to the new source folder.

Comment: post the code you tried with, so some body will copy, fix and post the solution asap